# @EnableWebSecurity possible with Pre-Authentication?

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying ***Spring Security 3.2RC2***. Is it possible to use `@EnableWebSecurity` with Pre-Authentication? I cannot find a configurer for that.

Comment: Paul, Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Use this annotation: `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class HelloMethodSecurityConfig {
    ...
}
```

[Source](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security)